# Discrete Math proving one-to-one/onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Im having issues understanding how to determine whether a function is one-to-one, onto, or a one-to-one correspondence. I understand the idea of these types of functions, but when it comes to discrete math I am not sure how to prove them.

Determine the type of function (onto, one to one, or one to one correspondence) and prove it:

f:ℚ → ℚ, f(r) = (4r/3)-1

f:ℕ → ℕ, f(n) = 4n + 1

f:ℤ → ℤ, f(n) =  {(n-1)/2 n is odd, 2n+1 n is even}

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Rather heavy handed hints: (1): $4(\frac{3}{4}(y+1))/3-1 = y$.  (2): $f(0)=1, f(1)=5, f(2)=9,\dots$.  (3): $2\times \color{red}{2}+1 = 5 = \frac{\color{red}{11}-1}{2}$